# Add4 Using Lambda Expression

Tags: functional-programming, lambda, lambda-calculus

I know that using lambda expressions, we can write `succ = λnfx • f (n f x )` and `twice = λfn • f f(n )`. My aim now is to write add4 using these two which adds 4 to the church numerals.

How do I write the beta-reduction steps for this?

Thanks for the help in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `twice succ` is a function that applies `succ` twice, so `twice (twice succ)` is a function that applies `twice succ` twice, thereby applying `succ` four times. So it should just be `add4 = twice (twice succ)`.

```
twice = λf.λn.(f (f n))
twice (twice succ)
=> twice (λf.λn.(f (f n)) succ)
=> twice λn.(succ (succ n))
=> λf.λn.(f (f n)) λn.(succ (succ n))
=> λf.λn.(f (f n)) λx.(succ (succ x))
=> λn.(λx.(succ (succ x)) (λx.(succ (succ x)) n))
=> λn.(λx.(succ (succ x)) (succ (succ n)))
=> λn.(succ (succ (succ (succ n))))
=> λn.(succ (succ (succ (succ n))))
```